# How to use scrollbar plugin in Angular 6 app?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating an app in Angular 6 and I want to change all the scrollbars to a custom one. I'm aiming for something similar to the Mac OS scrollbar;

1. Transparent
2. Over the content
3. Shows on mouse over

I want a method that will replace all and any scrollbar that will appear in the app to this custom one without altering the html.

I've been looking for an Angular/Typescript plugin to do this but each one I found is suggesting that I wrap my content in it's related selector. Which is not something I want to do. Or am I not understanding how to use this?

This one plugin I'm looking at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar

Is there a way to use this plugin without wrapping my content with `<perfect-scrollbar>`?

Sorry, I'm very new to Angular :(

I was also looking into Custom CSS scrollbars but that only works for webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

just use this :

```
const ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.scroll-container');
```

and set **scroll-container** class on all the elements that need scroll

Comment: It says: 
Uncaught Error: no element is specified to initialize PerfectScrollbar